# NSPredicate crash when I use a NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray, nspredicate

```
   +-----------+           +-----------+  
   | -Parada-  |           | -Autobus- |  
   +-----------+           +-----------+ 
   |  nombre   |           | circuito  | 
  +-------------+         +-------------+  
  |Relationships|         |Relationships|  
  +-------------+         +-------------+   
   |  byParada |<--------> |  parada   |
   +-----------+           +-----------+
```

I want to fetch some data using Core Data in the `setupFetchedResultsController`, the problem is that inside, in the `NSPredicate`, it crash when I want to filter using a `NSArray`.

This is the code:

```
NSArray  * myArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];

NSString *predString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"byParada.circuito IN %@", myArray2];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predString];
```

...And the results are these:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "byParada.circuito IN (
    1,
    2,
    3
)"'
```

In fact, if I erase all the numbers of `myArray2` leaving just one  ( `NSArray  * myArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",nil];`) NSPredicate works!

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try doing request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"byParada.circuito IN %@", myArray2]; instead of assigning that to a formatter string.

Comment: When it execute `[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil]`, it crash: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (byParada.circuito IN {"1", "2", "3"})'`

Comment: What is the data type of "circuito"? How is it defined in the model and does it have any relationship?

Comment: I've edited the first post, in the `setupFetchedResultsController` I'm using the entity `Parada` and `circuito` is defined as a String

Comment: Add ANY, like: request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY byParada.circuito IN %@", myArray2];

Comment: Good to hear that! I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to do to fix that. First, the formatted string should be made in predicateWithFormat, not in a NSString which is then passed to the predicate. Second, in one-to-many relationships, you have to include either ANY or ALL.

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY byParada.circuito IN %@", myArray2];
```